# Using padding to separate images inside a <div>

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, padding, viewport

Ok so I am working on my first responsive website that will be fluid and resize with the viewport. I have the page looking how I want it to for larger resolutions: 
http://i28.photobucket.com/albums/c250/WorldBalloonConvention/web/ScreenShot2014-08-28at41624PM_zps9c2e2e11.png

and it is essentially all inside of a div with the images aligned right and placed at different places through the text. I wanted to do it this way because creating two columns with div elements means that when I resize the page down to mobile size the pictures get tiny and stay in a column beside other text instead of just being forced below the text and keeping their size larger. The page looks good at mobile resolutions currently using this setup.

So both of those look how I want, however my iPad breakpoint causes the images to bump into each other and the padding used to space them apart is forcing the center image to move left as it bumps into the top images padding as shown in this image:
http://i28.photobucket.com/albums/c250/WorldBalloonConvention/web/ScreenShot2014-08-28at41656PM_zps63322273.png

Is there a better way to space the images to look how I want but that won't cause them to bump into each other as the viewport is resized? Currently this is the image padding:

```
.padimg {
padding-left:1%;
padding-top:4%;
padding-bottom:1%;
}
```

Thanks for your time, I am used to just needing to create a good viewport for a desktop so I am having to relearn how to create for a responsive layout.

Comment: I use the format described in my answer daily in my responsive design implementations. But I don't use inline CSS in my production code.

Comment: You have not responded, did the answer provided assist you in fixing your problem? Using the solution I describe below No matter what percentage-based width you place on the outer div, the images formatting will not break as in your example.

Comment: Yes, sorry it worked well enough for what I need and fixed the main issue even if it doesn't allow them to stack at various places throughout the text.

Comment: Hi @srafik, per your comment I updated the fiddle to reflect the request to stack at various places, I didn't catch that before as a requirement: [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/id_0t/7xxne0d4/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tough without you providing any code but here's a solid way to accomplish what you're requesting ([Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/id_0t/7xxne0d4/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<div style="float:right;">
    <ul style="display:block;">
        <li>one one one</li>
        <li>two two two</li>
        <li>three three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

****edit****

I've updated the demo to show how the above code can be used to sporadically disperse floating elements: [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/id_0t/7xxne0d4/1/)

Comment: While this wasn't exactly what I wanted (putting all three images in the same div means all three stack on top of each other, instead of stacking at various places throughout the text when the viewport is reduced) however it is the most effective solution for this particular instance as it does achieve everything else and I can deal will all three images just being located above the text when resized instead of stacking in at different places (which I had achieved the other way but kept running into the padding issue)